# importerror: no module named 'models' python anywhere

Tags: python, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

Trying to deploy local Django project on Python Anywhere, but receiving an ImportError: No module named 'models' when running "python manage.py createsuperuser"

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in
 execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in au
todiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in auto
discover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/myvenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/Ananthu/MCQ-app-mutile-choice-question-app-/quiz/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import Question,Result
     ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

This is the tree result

```
|--manage.py
|── qsystem
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── quiz
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── models.cpython-35.pyc
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
    │   └── css
    │       └── style.css
```

How can I solve this? Thankyou

Comment: Can you show your package's structure?

Comment: @ittus updated :)

Comment: try from  .models import Question or from quiz.models import Question

Comment: @Darshan this about deployment bro :) Nit about local development

Comment: You might find this PythonAnywhere help page useful: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from quiz.models import Question,Result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from .models import Question,Result
```

Comment: bro this is not the answer

Comment: if you are using django version 1.10 put the project app(quiz) into the qsystem and register the app in the installed apps in settings.py like(qsystem.quiz) then import the models in like from qsystem.quiz.models import model1,model2

Comment: its about deploying the site on the net